# How to make a type alias that references itself?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I made a few gateways / providers to integrate with an API in my API, using RX Swift and I'm trying to handle the pagination in what seems to me like a clean and simple way.

Basically, the function signature would look like that:

```
func getPlaces(with location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Observable<(value: [Place], next: Observable<(value: [Places], Observable<(value: [Place], next: ... ... >>
```

This quickly appears impractical, so I tried creating a typealias for that:

```
typealias Result = Observable<(value: [Place], next: Result?)>
```

So my function signature would look like this:

```
func getPlaces(with location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Result
```

But Xcode wouldn't get fooled so easily and calls me out for referencing my typealias inside itself

So... is it even doable ? How ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think this is possible using a `typealias` because you are creating an infinite type. The only way I can think of is to make `Observable` a recursive enumeration:

```
enum Observable {
   case end([Place])
   indirect case node([Place], Observable)
}
```

Comment: So, it works ! "Observable" is not appropriate, since it's an RxSwift type, but I mixed our approaches

Answer (score 2):

So, I mixed my approach with Nibr's, using a single case. This allows to handle pagination much more simply (in my opinion) from the ViewModel's side

```
enum Result<T> {
    indirect case node([T], Observable<Result>?)

    var value: [T] {
        if case let GatewayResult.node(value, _) = self {
            return value
        }
        return []
    }

    var next: Observable<Result>? {
        if case let GatewayResult.node(_, next) = self {
            return next
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```